# How do i reference a directory one level above web root in LAMP

Tags: php, apache, lamp

I'm trying to find the most effective(safest) way to utilise my own class Library which i want to put outside of public_html site root on a linux (shared hosting) server.
Several classes inside public_html in my site need to reference the classes outside the root and vise-versa. (see attached image)

[image]

```
Typically in one of my site classes in a directory on the root i have this line in a class: 
require_once("/home/my_isp_username/myCommonClasses/utilitybelt.php");
```

which should reference a class file (utilitybelt.php) one-level above the root.
Im getting a blank page and no errors returning; not even warnings, just a blank page.
Note (shared hosting so no access to Apache/PHP config files)

Anyone know the correct way to do this?

Comment: you can't, it violates the very principles of chroot.

Comment: Probably, depending on your host, you can manually set the root to a folder within public_html, but then... just have to figure out still how to reference above that root. Maybe with an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your web server does not have permissions to access files in that directory. On shared hosting I doubt that anyone will let you access it, so may be try moving the directory inside your web root.

Comment: I see other similar questions on SO where Op is on shared hosting and it seems possible but i dont see any conclusive reply as to what worked for them. Dont know if the ability to access this top level via ftp is any indication but i CAN upload and download to this top-level(above root) with no problems. On previous hosts it wasn't possible - but my current host i think it is